# The number of non-trivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I want to know the number of non-trivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\times \mathbb{Z}_p$. For example, for $p=2$, we have $6$ non-trivial subgroups. I think there exists only $3$ subgroups of order $p$.

Is there any formula for counting the number of subgroups $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, we have

- one subgroup of order $1$
- $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$, as the elements of order $p$ generate a subgroup of order $p^{2}$
- the just mentioned subgroup of order $p^{2}$
- $(p^{3} - p^{2})/(p^{2} - p) = p$ cyclic subgroups of order $p^{2}$
- the whole group.

In total, including the trivial subgroup and the whole group, we have
$$
2 p + 4
$$
subgroups.

For the general case, I would refer to [Goursat's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat's_lemma). It is spelled out in

> [Counting Subgroups in a Direct Product of Finite Cyclic Group
>   by Joseph Petrillo,
>   The College Mathematics Journal
>   Vol. 42, No. 3 (May 2011), pp. 215-222](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.42.3.215).

Comment: Can we say that every subgroup of order $p^2$ has the element $(p,0)$?

Comment: Yes, because if $H$ is a subgroup of order $p^{2}$ of $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $G/H$ has order $p$, and thus the $p$-th multiple of each element of $G$ is contained in $H$. In particular $p \cdot (1, 0) = (p, 0) \in H$.